# Sorting child rows in hasMany binding

Tags: cakephp

I have the following structure:

`Category hasMany CategoryDynamic`

When I use the Containable behavior, I want to get the `CategoryDynamic` data sorted by the `CategoryDynamic.language` field. For example, instead of the default structure:

```
array(
    'Category' => array(
        // ...
    ),
    'CategoryDynamic' => array(
        '0' => array(
            // ...
        ),
        '1' => array(
            // ...
        ),
    ),
);
```

I want to get them sorted by the `CategoryDynamic.language` field:

```
array(
    'Category' => array(
        // ...
    ),
    'CategoryDynamic' => array(
        'eng' => array(
            // ...
        ),
        'fra' => array(
            // ...
        ),
    ),
);
```

Can CakePHP do this by default, or do I need to modify the results in the `afterFind` function?

Comment: if you want updates data structure with keys `eng`, `fra` then answer is 'no', but if you want just right order, then 'yes'.  If you provide more context, at least fragment of source code, I think answer maybe more detailed

Comment: Well I don't know what kind of code to provide... I can explain a bit more, the `CategoryDynamic` table contains all the fields that are changed between languages, while `Category` contains only the tree structure data. What do you mean by "just right order"?

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp performs such solution if you use contain.

It can sort data from 'hasMany' relationship but doesn't return exact the way you have written.

CategroyModel:

```
class CategroyModel extends Model {
  public $actsAs = array('Containable');
  public $hasMany = array('CategoryDynamic');

  public function getData(){
    $conditions['contain'] = array(
        'CategoryDynamic' => array(
            'order' => 'CategoryDynamic.language ASC'
        )
    );
    return $this->find('first', $conditions);
  }
}
```

CategoryDynamicModel:

```
class CategoryDynamicModel extends Model {
  public $actsAs = array('Containable');
  public $belongsTo = array('Categroy'); 
}
```

Then when you call

```
$this->Categroy->getData();
```

in a controller, it will give sorted CategoryDynamic:

```
array(
    'Category' => array(
        // ...
    ),
    'CategoryDynamic' => array(
        0 => array(
            language => 'eng'
            // ...
        ),
        1 => array(
            language => 'fra'
            // ...
        ),
        ...
    ),
);
```

I can't run and check the exact code I posted above since I don't have the project or schema, but I have done some similar thing in my project and it has worked.

Comment: Alright then, I guess I'll sort the data manually in the `CategoryDynamic` afterFind() function.

Comment: That is also one solution but you should be careful to do custom sort in afterFind() function. Because in other situation ,you might want to sort CategoryDynamic in another way (for instance , id ASC) and afterFind() will prevent it.